# Python Insert new line if line has more than 50 characters

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, line, newline

I've been trying to figure out an issue on Python that's driving me crazy for couple of weeks...
I have a text file with a decent amount of text. Some of the lines has more than 50 characters and that an issue for me, because it has to be aligned to the text box.

My Question is :
How do I manage to insert new line  (\n) if a line on the text file has more than 50 characters (including spaces)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
  for line in infile:
    if len(line) > 50:
      outfile.write('\n'.join(line[i:i+50] for i in xrange(0,len(line), 50)))
    else:
      outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! Works like charm

Comment: You are fragmenting words this way.

Answer (score 10):

There is a library for this.  Try the following:

```
import textwrap

wrapped = textwrap.fill(YourText, 50)
```

Comment: This method didn't worked for me, because this just enters new line every 50 chars even with lines that have just 2 chars.

Comment: The above assumes that `YourText` is a single paragraph.